# Speech to text conversation through API

Tags: iphone, speech-to-text

Can anybody suggest API either free (that's very good) or paid to convert speech in to text for iPhone application.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition

Answer (score 1):

At one point I was going to look at trying to port this library to the iPhone:

http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/sphinx/tutorial.html

It has the capability to build your own speech dictionaries.