# speech to text application in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad

i am going to start a speech to text app in iphone and i need a start up for this can i have some open source or else to start with.

and i also need to know how to make speech to text more accurate almost upto 80% accuracy the list of helpful libraries and helpful examples are welcome ,

thanx in advance

Comment: See also [Speech Recognition.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118400/speech-recognition), [speech to text conversation through API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568531/speech-to-text-conversation-through-api)

Comment: Voice recognition is different than speech to text; different problem.  I think if we change the title to add "in iOS" it would be a more unique question.

Comment: @Stephano - However, the questions that are actually asked there do look for speech-to-text capabilities, so the answers are relevant to this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the Cocoa class for speech recognition.

Also, [O'Reilly](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mac/2004/03/17/speech.html) has some interesting things to say about working with speech on Mac OS 10.

Finally, there was a similar post here:

[iPhone App › Add voice recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)

As far as libraries go, I'm not sure you will find many specifically for iOS.  However, check out libraries like [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) and [Julius](http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php).  This will at least get you started in looking at how speech is it produced and perceived.

Good luck with your project.  That sounds like a really fun idea!

Comment: I don't believe speech recognition is available in iOS.  I think you're right to recommend CMU Sphinx-- they have an iOS library for voice commands and speech synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

I have founded some links which help for speech to text convertion

**speech to text SDK (not free)**

http://www.creaceed.com/ceedvocal/about

https://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone

**opensource SDK**

https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/03/ispeech-launches-free-mobile-sdk-to-bring-speech-recognition-to-ios-android-apps/

**opensource API**

http://www.macrumors.com/2012/08/06/nuance-releases-siri-like-api-for-third-party-mobile-apps/

http://applenapps.com/app-news/nuance-releases-siri-style-voice-recognition-apis-for-third-party-apps.html