# API or SDK for speech to text (speech recognition ) iPhone

Tags: ios, sdk, speech-recognition, speech

I want to have a speech recognition API or SDK which recognises the speech spoken by the user and gives it's text form.

Detailed Description is as follows:

In my application I need to play an audio file and text of which is already there with me. When audio starts playing the word should be highlighted which is spoken (from the audio file).

So if I am able to get the word from API or SDK then it is possible to highlight it.

Apart from I Googled a lot for API and I came across [ceedvocalsdk](http://www.creaceed.com/ceedvocalsdk/) but it's not available for free trial.

Can someone provide any idea other than this suiting to my requirement  or API or SDK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [speech to text application in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103771/speech-to-text-application-in-ios)

Comment: See also [iPhone speech recognition API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api) and [iPhone App › Add voice recognition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

As for speed, it should be fast, you probably don't use it properly. As I understood you have text already and you need to build grammar from this text.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit, but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: yes i downloaded but it takes too much time  for converting of speech to text so cannot use with my application requirement.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try Nexiwave.com.

I think the function you are looking for is what we can TimeStamping:
http://nexiwave.com/index.php/applications/for-transcription-companies

It basically take an audio and the text, we then put timestamp on each sentence and word.

Ben

Comment: The above link is not for iOS SDK.