# Speech to text in iOS Titanium

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am developing an iOS application in Titanium Appcelerator. I want help with speech to text functionality/api.
Is there any documentation available for the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) COCOA class as reference.
Also there is an project at [GITHUB](https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text), which might be of your interest. 
I have used [Openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) but for reverse purpose. Text to Speech.
Also there are multiple SO questions as well that you can refer to.
SO [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103771/speech-to-text-application-in-ios), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)

Comment: Thanks
      But i need a IOS in titanium