# Automatic Comparison of Pronounciation of Single Word

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, audio-fingerprinting

I want to make a simple game which compares the pronunciation of a given word, which is provided as audio file, with the same word pronounced by the player, via a microphone. By pronounciation I mean that the "sound" of the word should be compared to the given word.

It would be ideal if the system would give back a percentage of how close the player pronounced the word to the given word.

I've found questions in StackOverflow about [audio fingerprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471165/comparing-sound-files-if-not-completely-identical) and [speech-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387062/ios-c-algorithm-to-detect-phonemes). They seem to indicate, that its a very hard problem. But as I don't need full speech recognition maybe there is a simpler approach which I missed.

So my questions are then: Is that even feasible? If it is feasible, how could I approach the problem? Are there libraries which could support my.

Comment: Does this have to use javascript?  If so, you'll need to specify a platform, as not all systems have SR systems accessible from JavaScript.

Comment: It would be great if it is somehow accesible in javascript. But I am more interested how you could do it in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in JavaScript, but my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746850/finding-pronunciation-correctness/16805040#16805040) outlines an approach to solve the problem.  You'll likely need to use C++, as the relevant SAPI interfaces aren't really exposed via C#.