# Voice to text in ios

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone App › Add voice recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)

I have a textfield and a button.On button click , I want to recognize the voice of the user and want to convert the voice to text.How can I implement this?

Please anybody help me on this.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Hemang I am trying Openears but dont have any idea about that.