# Adding speech to text functionality to iOS app

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech

I am going to create an iOS app (with Swift) with feature of converting speech into text and display that text in a Label.

Can anyone please tell me can I implement the feature of converting speech into text and display it in a Label?

Comment: Find proof of concept, start coding, come back if you hit a blocker somewhere. This question is too broad and hence flagging it as such

Comment: I searched for the same on google but could not found anything on native iOS. I don't want to go for third party SDK or Library.

Comment: 3rd Party SDKs are your only option here. See this Question for reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition

Answer (score 2):

There is not any built-in framework for speech-to-text in iOS SDK. But you can try these third party APIs: iSpeech or OpenEars

Comment: ispeech is free or paid?

Answer (score 1):

you can use speech kit but this not native ios... Nsnoob is correct there is no native library to convert speech to text 
you can get help from this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri

Comment: That is built on  Nuance Dragon Mobile SDK. It is not a Native SDK as desired by the OP